# Xamarin.Forms : how to reproduce this UI that combines embedded layouts

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms, grid

I try to reproduce this UI on a page:
[image: Expeceted UI]

The page contains:

- the **"main" item** that is displayed at the top
- the **"other" items** that are displayed at the bottom on 2 columns

I'm already  able to display the image of the main item, and the other items with a XAML that looks like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="450" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Main item  -->
        <StackLayout MinimumHeightRequest="450" HeightRequest="450">
            <ffil:CachedImage Source="{Binding MainProduct.Icon}"      
                              MinimumHeightRequest="450" HeightRequest="450" 
                              Aspect="AspectFill"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- Other items -->
        <!-- through the use of 2 Repeaters -->
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

But when I try to add the content that is displayed on the main item's Image, I encounter a problem: the page **is no longer displayed** cause the app encounters an error when the page is instancied.

I've added a **secondary Grid** that is placed in the **first Row of the existing Grid**, cause I hoped that shoud help me to show the related content of the main item on the Image:

```
<ScrollView>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="450" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Main item  -->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="**" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                   
            <StackLayout MinimumHeightRequest="450" HeightRequest="450"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <ffil:CachedImage Source="{Binding MainProduct.Icon}" 
                                  MinimumHeightRequest="450" HeightRequest="450" 
                                  Aspect="AspectFill"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="Black"
                   Opacity="0.75"
                   Margin="10"
                   VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End"
                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding MainProduct.Title}" 
                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    ...
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Other items -->
        <!-- through the use of 2 Repeaters -->
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

***What's wrong in my XAML? Is there a better way to achieve this through RelativeLayout or AbsoluteLayout?***

**Edit**

the error is the following:

> {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException:
>   One of the identified items was in an invalid format.   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.GridLengthTypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString
>   (System.String value) [0x000a0] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\GridLengthTypeConverter.cs:24
>   at MyProjectTablet.Views.ListProductPage.InitializeComponent ()
>   [0x00012] in
>   C:\Projets\MyProject\MyProjectNewUi\DevMyProjectNewUi\tablet\MyProjectTablet\MyProjectTablet\obj\Debug\MyProjectTablet.Views.ListProductPage.xaml.g.cs:21
>   at MyProjectTablet.Views.ListProductPage..ctor () [0x00008] in
>   C:\Projets\MyProject\MyProjectNewUi\DevMyProjectNewUi\tablet\MyProjectTablet\MyProjectTablet\Views\ListProductPage.xaml.cs:24
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0     --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke
>   (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00017] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic)
>   [0x000a8] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly,
>   System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache,
>   System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00009] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean
>   publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache,
>   System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00027] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean
>   nonPublic) [0x0002c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   MobileCommon.Services.NavigationService.CreatePage
>   (MobileCommon.Services.PageType pageType, System.Object parameters)
>   [0x00053] in
>   C:\Projets\MyProject\MyProjectNewUi\DevMyProjectNewUi\mobile\MobileCommon\Services\NavigationService.cs:118
>   }

***I don't understand why I get an exception related to the GridLengthTypeConverter...***

Comment: "app encounters an error" - what is the specific error?  You should be able to do with with a single 2x2 grid, where the first row spans 2 columns

Comment: HI @Jason I've added the exception details: "System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in fact very different - you accidentally used `**` instead of `*` as in one of the `ColumnDefinitions`:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="**" />
```

To illustrate how I noticed this is by looking at the exception stack trace. You can see the second line says `Xamarin.Forms.GridLengthTypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString (System.String value)`. This points you to the source of the error quite well.

To get a `n:1` ratio of column sizes, you need to write `n*` where `n` is a number, instead of `**`, , like:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
```

Comment: That happens :-) . Happy coding!